# Is there a way to script creation of a user on a Chef server without including a cleartext password?

Tags: chef-infra

As near as I can tell from the documentation of `chef-server-ctl user-create`, the command requires a cleartext password as one of its arguments.  However, in scripting setup of a Chef server, I'd really like to avoid at all costs including anything like:

```
chef-server-ctl user-create jsmith John Smith jsmith@foo.com acleartextpasswordinmygitrepo
```

Is there some alternate solution that exists in Chef, or do I need to choose between manual intervention, some external workaround, or the above ugliness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR as long as you do not use Chef Server's Web UI, these passwords are not used anywhere (the client.pem keys are), so you can set them random.

If you really want to change a password later you can do it through psql directly as said in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/29005708/170230

This does not require a plain text password, but its hash.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the external authentication integration (AD, SAML, etc) so that Chef doesn't deal with passwords. Alternatively if you do want Chef to manage users you can let people create their own accounts and use the invite system.